# How to create a preimage which is the batch of other preimages?

Tags: polkadot-js, democracy, batch, preimage

I am wondering whether, and if so how, it is possible to submit a preimage which batches over other preimages, e.g.

```js
const pre1= '0x09401eb25e90bf587fbde8d2a9be8af5ac0f3187f02f4e9e9f1f178b0314ebe5';
const pre2 = '0x006de81a9bc71fe5929b9a36ee26c3a8cd8648f64ab9e1f0282d6bab8f91b7ae';

const batchCall = api.tx.utility.batch([pre1, pre2]);
const preimage = api.tx.preimage.notePreimage(batchCall.method.toHex());
```

I did not succeed doing so using Polkadot Js Apps or pure Polkadot Js. For now it seems like I need to instead submit a new preimage which batches over the re-played calls encoded in `pre1` and `pre2`.